# Given a axis aligned rectangle and a triangle. How do tell if they overlap

Tags: geometry

I have:

1. rectangle which is described by `center x, center y, width, height`
2. triangle, which is described by `{x1,y1} {x2,y2} {x3,y3}`

How do I tell if they collide (have any intersection at all)?

I am currently thinking that I can iterate each of the 3 line segments of the triangle and then check against the 4 line segments of the rectangle and see if only of the line segments overlap